# How do I access nested objects properties in console.table()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Lets say I have the following array of objects:

```
var data = [
  { id: 123, author: { id: 123 } },
  { id: 123, author: { id: 123 } }
];
```

How can I populate a column in console.table with the id property of the author object?

This does not seem to work: `console.table(data, ['id', 'author.id']);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it with nested properties.

You could use `map` to pull the data out into a better format and then `console.table` it:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 123, author: { id: 123 } },
  { id: 123, author: { id: 123 } }
];

const out = data.map(obj => {
  return {
    id: obj.id,
    authorId: obj.author.id
  };
});

console.table(out);
```

Note: you cannot hide the `index` column.

Comment: Yea, I had a look at it for a moment... Doesn't seem possible out of the box. I'd replace that `console.log()` with `console.table`, though, since then you have exactly the result the OP wants ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that is a possible solution. But not quite what I was looking for.